# Uncaught Reference Error: (function) is not defined JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling

```
const markProperties = {
    fullName: 'Mark Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,
        calcBMI: function () {
        return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    },
    bmi: calcBMI()



    


}

const johnProperties = {
    fullName: 'John Smith',
    mass: 92,
    height: 1.95,

    calcBMI: function () {
        this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
        return this.bmi;
    },
    bmi: calcBMI()
};

const checkWinner = () => {
    if (johnProperties.bmi > markProperties.bmi) {
        return "John's BMI (" + johnProperties.bmi + ") is higher than Mark's BMI (" + markProperties.bmi + ")";
    } else if (markProperties.bmi > johnProperties.bmi) {
        return "Mark's BMI (" + markProperties.bmi + ") is higher than John's BMI (" + johnProperties.bmi + ")";
    }
}
console.log(checkWinner());
```

This is the code and it says that the function inside both objects is not defined. As I said, It brings an error that reads: error: Uncaught ReferenceError: calcBMI is not defined

Comment: It would help enormously if you could edit your question so that your code is properly formatted.

Comment: not to mention explaining what exactly is the issue.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defining an object, you can't execute a function that is being defined in the object.
In your case you should simply set a getter for `bmi` property instead:

```js
const markProperties = {
    fullName: 'Mark Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,

    get bmi() {
        return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    }
}

const johnProperties = {
    fullName: 'John Smith',
    mass: 92,
    height: 1.95,

    get bmi() {
        return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    }
};

const checkWinner = () => {
    if (johnProperties.bmi > markProperties.bmi) {
        return "John's BMI (" + johnProperties.bmi + ") is higher than Mark's BMI (" + markProperties.bmi + ")";
    } else if (markProperties.bmi > johnProperties.bmi) {
        return "Mark's BMI (" + markProperties.bmi + ") is higher than John's BMI (" + johnProperties.bmi + ")";
    }
}
console.log(checkWinner());
```